# Change SELinux policy for dovecot on alternative home folder

Tags: linux, selinux, dovecot

I have my users home directories in /userdata instead of /home. SELinux blocks Dovecot access to the folders under /userdata. How can I add the /userdata folder to the SELinux policy for Dovecot?

Answer (score 0):

Made it work after inspecting selinux label on folder in /home (user_home_t). Set this selinux label via policy on the new home folder & subfolders. E.g. /userdata